# Why does `mkdir -pm` not set the permissions I asked for?

Tags: permissions, mkdir

I created some directories with the command `mkdir -pm 700 /tmp/a/b/c`

I was surprised to find that `/tmp/a` had permissions `775` rather than the `700`, I had requested.

Is there some reason for `mkdir` to only apply the specified mode to the last directory created and ignore it for the parent directories?

Answer (score 7):

This is required by the POSIX [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) for `mkdir`:

For the `-p` option:

> Create any missing intermediate pathname components.

followed by:

> and then calling the chmod() function with the following arguments:
>
> 1. The same path argument as in the mkdir() call
> 2. The value (S_IWUSR|S_IXUSR|~filemask)&0777 as the mode argument, where filemask is the file mode creation mask of the process

This means it only runs `chmod` on the final directory in the path.

Comment: Actually, the part you are citing applies to each directory it creates. The important part of the spec to cite would be the `mode` argument for the `chmod` call, which you omitted in your citation.

Comment: Are you sure? `-p` "Creates any missing intermediate pathname components" which creates, as it says, the cild paths including all missing parents. AND THEN "calling the chmod() function with... The same path argument as in the mkdir() call", which calls `chmod` with the full path passed to the `mkdir` command. That's how I read it anyway.

Comment: Then you are misreading it. It says that for each of the missing components it must first create it with mode `0` (which means even the owner won't have access), and next it must `chmod` it with a mode, that doesn't even depend on the `-m` command line argument. If it applied that `chmod` system call to only the last directory, the second `mkdir` system call would fail because the first had created a directory in which the owner did not have write permissions.

Comment: @Gilles You are linking to an older version of the spec. I am referring to the newer version, which garethTheRed linked to. The specific section of the spec, which I was referring to doesn't exist in the older version, which you linked to.

Comment: @Gilles Exactly, which is why I pointed out that this is the important part of the spec, and that it had been omitted from the citation.

Comment: @kasperd Oh, sorry, I'd misread your comment. garethTheRed: the [previous version of the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/mkdir.html) puts it in terms that you may find clearer: the description of `-p` gives the equivalent command `mkdir -p -m $(umask -S),u+wx $(dirname dir) && mkdir [-m mode] dir`.

Comment: I missed the zero as the `mode` part.  @Gilles - that previous version was much easier to understand.